# Handling SIGINT with shared memory and semaphores

Tags: c, signals, posix, semaphore, shared-memory

I tried to write a shared memory and semaphores program that runs until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed i.e. `SIGINT` is received:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define SHM_NAME "/shm"
#define SEM_1 "/sem_1"
#define SEM_2 "/sem_2"
#define SEM_3 "/sem_3"

static volatile sig_atomic_t run;

struct sharedMemory{
    int done;
};
static struct sharedMemory *shared;

static void handleSIGINT(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGINT){
       printf(" SIGINT caught: sig = %d\n", sig);
       shared->done = 1;
       run = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // setup shared memory and semaphores
    int shmfd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
    if (shmfd == -1){
        // handle error 
    }

    if (ftruncate(shmfd, sizeof(struct sharedMemory)) == -1){
        // handle error 
    }

    shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);
    if (shared == MAP_FAILED){
       // close resources
    }

    sem_t *sem_read = sem_open(SEM_1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);
    sem_t *sem_write = sem_open(SEM_2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, BUFFER_SIZE);
    // sem open error handling
    if (sem_read == SEM_FAILED)
       // close resources 

    if (sem_write == SEM_FAILED)
       // close resources 

    // settup signal handler
    signal(SIGINT, handleSIGINT);

    while (!run)
    {
        sem_wait(sem_read);

        // read from shared memory and store data or set shared->done to 1 to stop generator process

        sem_post(sem_write);
    }

    // close resources
    printf("exiting\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  is pressed `volatile` `run` is set to `1` and it breaks out of loop and exits. This works fine without shared memory and semaphores, but here I never get `exiting` string on `stdout` only `SIGINT caught: sig = 2` and it continues to run.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour you are seeing is the way the signal handler is being installed:

```
signal(SIGINT, handleSIGINT);
```

By default, `signal` enables the `SA_RESTART` flag. Which means that the `sem_wait` will be restarted after the signal handler has been called.

This is one of the main reasons for using `sigaction` instead of `signal`. Change the above line to the below code and it should work as you require.

```
struct sigaction saction;
saction.sa_handler = handleSIGINT;
sigemptyset(&saction.sa_mask);
saction.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction (SIGINT, &saction, NULL);
```

Not directly part of your question but it is advisable to call `sem_unlink` on `SEM_1` and `SEM_2` as well as check the return values of the `sem_open` calls. Since `O_EXCL` is set in the `sem_open` it will fail if you run the program again after force terminating a previous invocation with `kill`.

Comment: I intentionally ignored the error handling part to make a question more focused on my main problem but thank you reminding me to add that! `unlinking` and `closing` is what I meant with `//close resources` comment.